# How to create a halftone pattern on a transparent png image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I tried searching for a tutorial but I couldn't find a way to create a halftone pattern on a png file with a transparent background. I am looking for the output file to be a transparent file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't apply the halftone filter in Photoshop (i.e. if it's greyed out), then it's likely because the PNG is in Indexed colour mode. The halftone filter has no problem with transparency.

To fix it click *Image > Mode > RGB*

Next click *Filter > Pixelate > Colour Halftone*

If you want a monochrome halftone, convert it to Greyscale mode instead, then run the filter.

Answer (score -1):

This is a photo with transparent background

[image]

I guess you have tried different halftoning receipes for artistical reasons and many of them replaced the transparency with white solid background like this:

[image]

That's because halftoning means presenting different brightness values with different solid black dot or line densities. The result can have only 2 colors in the palette: black and white.

You probably have tried to remove the white background, but deleting white leaves only the black dots and you want only the original transparent areas to be transparent again. Making a new clipping path needs too much work altough just now it's easy due the simple edge. Ideally the transparency should be copied from the original, but halftoning filters do not all do it.

It's well possible, copy the original image to the halftoned one as a new layer. Be sure to convert the halftoned version to RGB before.

You probably must scale the original because halftoning has changed the image size. Stretching the original to the right size can be calculated and with some careful parametrization math before the halftoning process the size can be right as is. But it goes also well with transform handles if you have blending mode Multiply or reduced layer opacity to see both at the same time.

Beware to scale the half-toned image. It's dots or lines will get blurred in resampling.

After placing the original make a selection by Ctrl+Click the layer icon of the original image:

[image]

Copy and paste the halftoned version to a new layer with that selection. Shut the other layers and in theory you have a fixed image ready to export as PNG:

[image]

But it's only theory. The edge very easily needs some fixing. Insert a differently colored test background to see it:

[image]

There's some too white edge areas. That can be lousy background removal or wrong placement or a halftone happens to be 100% white although the original was only nearly white in the same place.

Fix it manually with the eraser. You probably want to erase only some white, but save all black. Make a duplicate and erase from it all white with the magic wand+DEL. (=Black only) Then edit the excessive white OFF with eraser at the edges:

[image]

When it looks ok, merge the black only layer and the edge fixed layer. Remove the extra layers after you are 100% sure it's ok and save as PNG.

BTW the black only version can be useful as is, if you have a light new background where the result is used:

[image]

Comment: That isn't a halftone. It's dithering.

Comment: Halftoning covers all methods to create greyshades or different color brightness levels by varying the density of dots or lines which all have the same color.. This example maybe is called dithering by some filter maker, but it's made in PS with  blurred noise  and  tresholding. Halftoning with different patterns has been used at least 500 years to create printed greyshades. Computer software writers used term dithering when they started to present greyshades with the same idea on screens which had only black and white and 0...2 greys between them.